# Twenty students in a class when they are required to choose a partner

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question consists of two subquestions:

There are 20 students in the class.

***A.*** The students are required to divide into 10 pairs. In how many ways can they are divided?

***Attempt:*** First of all, we know that there are 20 students so in the first stage we can arrange them in upline so we get 20! for that, In the second stage, we determine two students in the line will be pair and the change between them makes the calculation $2^n$, the last stage we can see of each pair can be move in the line together which gives us the $10!$.

Final solution: $\frac{20!}{10!\cdot 2^{10}}$.

This solution correct?

***B.*** The students are required to divide into pairs again, however, they cannot be with the same partners as in subquestion - ***A.***. In how many ways can they do so?

***Attempt:***  I tried to use the inclusion-exclusion principle without any success.

Comment: What is the "$n$" in $2^n$? Also, inclusion exclusion is the right way to go, so can you include your progress in your post? What are the "bad sets" being subtracted out? If you do not know how to get started, at least write out the general method for inclusion exclusion, and say what part you cannot figure out how to apply here.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I regard part (B) as no walk in the park.  It seems to be a complicated variation of the [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) problem, where the partner that you had in part (A) is considered the *right* partner.

Comment: @MikeEarnest it was a mistake I am sorry. It has fixed by ATB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your attempt on section **A**, the naïve approach of lining up the students and pairing them off leads to $20!$ scenarios, which we can then assess to find which other scenarios will produce the same ten pairs. We can rearrange the pairs in $10!$ ways, and we can rearrange each pair of students, $2$ options per pair. These changes are independent of each other - these rearrangements can't cancel each other out. So for any set of pairs, there are $10!\cdot 2^{10}$ scenarios that will generate those same ten pairs. So overall we have $\dfrac{20!}{10!\cdot 2^{10}}$ different pairings here.

For section **B**,  we'll call the section **A** result $\mathcal P_{20}$, for making pairings from $20$ students. Now for reducing this total, we can consider how many different pairings exist with $18$ students (assuming a pairing carried over from the first time) - call this $\mathcal P_{18}$, calculated in a similar way to section **A**. Then also calculate how many for $16$ students (two pairings carried over), $\mathcal P_{16}$, etc. Now combine all these results using inclusion-exclusion to remove over- and under-counts from each adjustment based on choosing pairs from the first pairing:
$$ \mathcal P_{20} - \binom{10}{1}\mathcal P_{18} + \binom{10}{2}\mathcal P_{16} - \binom{10}{3}\mathcal P_{14}  + \binom{10}{4}\mathcal P_{12} - \binom{10}{5}\mathcal P_{10} \\ + \binom{10}{6}\mathcal P_{8} - \binom{10}{7}\mathcal P_{6} + \binom{10}{8}\mathcal P_{4} - \binom{10}{9}\mathcal P_{2}+ \binom{10}{10}\mathcal P_{0}$$ (noting that $\mathcal P_{2}=\mathcal P_{0}=1$)

Comment: First, thank you! Secondly, I forgot to mention a detail that might change the answer in ***A.***. The detail: the order between the pairs isn't important and the inner order of the pairs also doesn't matter. Is that changing anything? or since those orders aren't important, we need to divide all the options by them?

Comment: That order-invariance is why we do the division; $10!$ because the order of the pairs doesn’t matter and $2^{10}$ because the order within the pairs doesn’t matter.

Comment: I cannot understand your solution for ***B.***. What is $\mathcal{P}$? can you elaborate more about your answer to this subquestion?

Comment: @Joffan Thanks you for the answer, however, if you can explain what to do with the last equation to get the final solution, what is exactly the $P_{20}$ mean for us?, and how we can continue to the final sol, Thanks a lot and I appreciate that much.

Comment: Clarified what the $\mathcal P_x$ values mean and wrote out the full inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for that Clarified, btw the last two binomials in the equation have minus (-) that is a mistake, or it's correct? i mean that $- \binom{10}{9}\mathcal P_{2}- \binom{10}{10}\mathcal P_{0}$

Comment: Much more elegant than my answer.

Comment: Thanks for asking! the thing that I found unclear is the subtract and additional factors, you said: "remove over- and under-counts", why it sometimes with plus and sometimes with minus? other than that, your answer is clear.

Comment: @aasc232 it's a fairly standard [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle) calculation - take the full set, remove the options that don't qualify, add back in the options that have been removed twice by that process, remove the options that have been wrongly added back because they qualified three times, etc

Comment: Thank you so much!!! if I will have further questions I will ask.

Answer (score 3):

Re-reading my answer, I discovered analysis that expedites the math involved in the recursion approach.  Rather than force the reader to delve into the long-winded article, I will repeat the appropriate math up front.

Assume that $n$ is an even number $\geq 6$, and that $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are as defined at the very start of this answer.

$\underline{\text{Original Derived Formulas}}:$ 
$$\displaystyle f(n+2) = [n \times f(n-2)] + (n)(n-2) ~g(n-2).\tag1$$
$$g(n+2) = f(n) + n \times g(n).\tag2$$

Using equation (2), you have that 
$\displaystyle g(n) = f(n-2) + (n-2)~g(n-2) \implies$
$\displaystyle (n-2)~g(n-2) = g(n) - f(n-2).$

Applying this to equation (1) you have that

$$f(n+2) = [n \times f(n-2)] + (n)~[g(n) - f(n-2)] = n ~g(n).\tag3 $$

Note that equation (3) can be alternatively derived by re-examining the analysis in my proof of the first original  formula [i.e. the one for $f(n+2)$].  I simply never noticed this relationship before.

Because of equation (3), I can now conclude that 
$\displaystyle f(n) = (n-2)g(n-2)$.
This allows me to immediately re-write equation (1) as
$$f(n+2) = n[f(n) + f(n-2)].\tag4 $$

Equation (4), which seems to represent an *offbeat* variation of the Fibonacci sequence, allows the helper function $g(n)$ to be dispensed with, when calculating $f(n)$.

---

---

**start of original answer**

Alternate (inferior) approach

First of all, I definitely consider Joffan's approach superior to what I am going to offer.  My approach, which requires more intermediate calculations, is based on recursion.  I derived the necessary formulas, after considering [the Derangement Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Throughout the remainder of this answer, it is assumed that $n$ is an even integer $\geq 6$.

Consider the following pairing and sets:

Baseline pairing to be avoided:

$$P_n = [1-2], [3-4], [5-6], \cdots, [(n-1)(n)].$$

Elements to be paired

$$S_n = \{1,2,3, \cdots, (n-1), n\}.$$

$$T_n = \{1,2,3 \cdots, (n-1), (n+1)\}.$$

Note that $S_n$ has the exact same elements as are used to form the $P_n$ pairing, while $T_n$ has replaced exactly one element from $S_n$ with an *out of range* element.

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of ways of pairing the elements in $S_n$ such that each of the pairs in $P_n$ are avoided.

Let $g(n)$ denote the number of ways of pairing the elements in $T_n$ such that each of the pairs in $P_n$ are avoided.

First, I'll give the formulas, then I'll justify them, then, I'll use them.

$\underline{\text{Formulas}}:$ 
$\displaystyle f(n+2) = [n \times f(n-2)] + (n)(n-2) g(n-2).$ 
$\displaystyle g(n+2) = f(n) + n \times g(n).$

$\underline{\text{Proof}}:$ 
Consider the elements $\{1,2,3, \cdots, (n-1), n, (n+1), (n+2)\}$ 
with may be paired up in $f(n+2)$ ways.

When computing $f(n+2)$, $(n+2)$ itself, may not be paired with $(n+1)$.  There are therefore, $n$ valid choices that $(n+2)$ may be paired with.  You can assume, without loss of generality, that $(n+2)$ is paired with $(n)$, compute the number of possible pairings based on this, and then multiply the computation by $(n)$.

Assuming that $[(n+2),(n)]$ are paired up, $(n-1)$ may then be paired with any of the $(n-1)$ elements from $\{1,2,3,\cdots,(n-2), (n+1)\}.$

If $(n-1)$ pairs with $(n+1)$, then the remaining elements are
$\{1,2,3,\cdots,(n-3),(n-2)\}$, which may be paired up in $f(n-2)$ ways.

Suppose instead that $(n-1)$ pairs with any of the $(n-2)$ other available elements.  I will illustrate what happens if $(n-1)$ specifically pairs with $(n-2)$.  If it pairs with any of the other available elements, besides $(n+1)$, the result will be the same.

With the two pairs of $[(n+2),(n)]$ and $[(n-1),(n-2)]$, you will then have the remaining elements 
$\{1,2,3,\cdots, (n-4),(n-3),(n+1)\}$.

These elements correspond to the elements used to form $P_{(n-2)}$, except that one element has been replaced by the *out of range* element $(n+1)$.  In this scenario, with $[(n-1),(n-2)]$ paired, the remaining elements may be paired in exactly $g(n-2)$ ways.

In summary, $(n+2)$ has $n$ valid choices. 
Assuming that $[(n+2),(n)]$ are paired then

If $(n-1)$ pairs specifically with $(n+1)$ you are left with $f(n-2)$ ways that the remaining elements may be paired.

Alternatively, if $(n-1)$ pairs with any of the other $(n-2)$ elements, you will be left with $g(n-2)$ ways that the remaining elements may be paired.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle f(n+2) = n \times [f(n-2) + (n-2)g(n-2)].$

---

Now consider the elements $\{1,2,3, \cdots, (n-1), n, (n+1), (n+3)\}$ 
with may be paired up in $g(n+2)$ ways.

If $(n+3)$ specifically pairs with $(n+1)$ then the remaining elements may be paired in $f(n)$ ways.  Otherwise, you will have a scenario equivalent to what would happen if 
$(n+3)$ paired with $(n)$.

Assume that $(n+3)$ pairs with $(n)$.  Then, the remaining elements, 
$\{1,2,\cdots, (n-1), (n+1)\}$ may be paired in $g(n)$ ways.  Since this second scenario will apply if $(n+3)$ is paired with any element besides $(n+1)$, you have that 
$g(n+2) = f(n) + [n \times g(n)].$

---

$\underline{\text{Usage}}:$ 
I did the following calculations manually, using the derived formulas:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  n & f(n) & g(n) \\
  \hline                       
  2 & 0 & 1 \\
  4 & 2 & 2 \\
  6 & 8 & 10 \\
  8 & 60 & 68 \\
  10 & 544 & 604 \\
  12 & 6,040 & 6,584 \\
  14 & 79,008 & 85,048 \\
  16 & 1,190,672 & 1,269,680 \\
  18 &  &  \\
  20 & 387,099,936 &  \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

I intentionally skipped $f(18), g(18),$ and $g(20)$ since these three specific intermediate calculations were not needed for my goal calculation of $f(20)$.

These results were *partially* sanity checked in two different ways.  My java program balked when calculating $f(n)$ for $n > (12).$  Therefore, I then simply manually plugged in joffan's formula for

$$ \mathcal P_{20} - \binom{10}{1}\mathcal P_{18} + \binom{10}{2}\mathcal P_{16} - \binom{10}{3}\mathcal P_{14} \cdots.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very impressive and formal, however, it is very long and hard to understand :(.

Comment: @ATB I agree with your criticism.  However, I'm not sure if any portions can be omitted, or if the answer can be re-organized, or if there is a clear way of editing any portions of the answer.  In particular, I'm not thrilled about the language that I used to prove the formulas.  However, no ready improvement of the proofs comes to mind; the proofs do involve complicated ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, do

$$\frac{\text{(# students)}!}{\text{(# pairs)}! 2^{\text{# pairs}}}$$

So, you're answer is nearly correct, the $2^n$ should just be $2^{10}$.

Answer (score -1):

Part A:

Label each student $1,\dots,20$. Pair student $1$ off ($19$ ways to do this). Regroup all the remaining students, and relabel $1,\dots,18$. Pair student $1$ off ($17$ ways to do this), regroup, etc...

This gives $19!!=19\cdot17\cdots3\cdot1$ ways to pair the students of.

Which is the same as $\frac{20!}{10!2^{10}}=\frac{20\cdot19\cdots1}{2\cdot10\cdot2\cdot9\cdots2\cdot1}$, just a different way of counting them.